# What is the difference between "fold" and "unfold"?

Tags: isabelle

I'm doing an exercise using Isabelle recently and don't know the difference between `fold` and `unfold`. What I know is to apply the rules which contain inference symbol, we should use `rule` and those without inference symbol, we should use `unfold`. But when should we use `fold`? Some examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, these are not really keywords; they are just proof methods. `unfold` unfolds an equation (usually a definition); `fold` folds it. That means that `unfold` rewrites with the given equations left-to-right, while `fold` rewrites with them right-to-left.